# EDI x12 mapper for c# object data sources

Tags: c#, x12

Does anyone know any tool that can map EDI x12 to C# objects?  I just looked at Altova MapForce but it does not seem to support this. I can't use database schema mapping for portability reasons ... and I'd rather avoid xml or flat file if I can.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, MapForce does support this using an add-in package they have available (not sure if it's free or not). I evaluated MapForce about a year ago for this very purpose (mapping EDI x12 835i and 835p files to a database).

Here's the link for the EDI-Mapping page for MapForce that specifically mentions ANSI x12 mapping: http://www.altova.com/products/mapforce/edi-mapping.html

MapForce actually generates C# or Java code for a complete application that will do the mapping you set up; you can use the classes from that application in your own code instead.

Comment: Please note that mapforce will not may object data sources. Take a look at MapForce again before you vote up to avoid misleading readers.

The C#/Java mapforce generates for you is to run the mapping you already did. And the mapping options does not include object graphs.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer.  You can create a temporary database locally, do the mapping, generate the code, then throw the database away and just use the classes it created.  That's how I set up my web service, using Altova's Map Force.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Symphonia: http://www.orionhealth.com/products/symphonia/

-Dave